# Is there an actual prop of the Monolith that was used in 2001?

Tags: props, 2001-a-space-odyssey

The monolith from the final scene of *2001: A Space Odissey* with the old man in bed lifting hand as if to touch the monolith from the bed. Where are these props?

Comment: According  to a [Hollywood.com article](http://www.hollywood.com/movies/get-thee-to-the-geek-2001-a-space-odyssey-room-237-57243937/): "13. Kubrick had all of 2001’s sets, props, and miniatures destroyed so they would never be able to be recycled for future movies, the way Forbidden Planet’s props surfaced in later films."

Comment: @CGCampbell - IIRC they had to rebuild the Discovery model from scratch for 2010: Odyssey Two since the original was destroyed.

Comment: You might still get one of [these](http://gizmodo.com/5668811/2001-a-space-odyssey-monolith-action-figure-will-leave-your-other-toys-in-cosmic-awe), if that satisfies your needs.

Comment: I remember hearing that Kubrick had a habit of destroying the outtakes, didn't think he'd do the same with props., Kinda makes me wonder if the set of "The Shining" really burnt down or was set on fire. Ahhh man! That action figure rocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to buy an actual prop used for the movie, you may be out of luck as according to a [Hollywood.com article](http://www.hollywood.com/movies/get-thee-to-the-geek-2001-a-space-odyssey-room-237-57243937/):

> 13. Kubrick had all of 2001’s sets, props, and miniatures destroyed so they would never be able to be recycled for future movies, the way Forbidden Planet’s props surfaced in later films.

Of course, there may have been reproductions made for personal use/enjoyment, etc. Good luck with your continued search for extra-dimensional education.